# Silverstripe page template save to database issues

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, silverstripe

Been having a few issues with some tab fields that I've added not saving data placed in them. I know it has somehting to do with the $db array but I can't get it to work without error when I try /dev/build.

Here is my code snippet. I'm trying to add in 5 HTMLEditorFields as below. I'm pretty new to this but all the posts i've come across such as these suggest that I've got it right?

http://www.silverstripe.org/customising-the-cms/show/4496

http://www.silverstripe.org/customising-the-cms/show/9391

http://www.silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/9001

I wonder if anyone can point out what my issue might be?

```
    <?php
class HomePage extends Page {

    static $db = array(
        'contentBottom'     => 'HTMLText',
        'centerTop'         => 'HTMLText',
        'centerBottom'      => 'HTMLText',
        'rightTop'          => 'HTMLText',
        'rightBottom'       => 'HTMLText'
    );


    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        // Content
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Main', new HtmlEditorField('contentBottom'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Main', new HtmlEditorField('centerTop'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Main', new HtmlEditorField('centerBottom'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Main', new HtmlEditorField('rightTop'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Main', new HtmlEditorField('rightBottom'));

        return $fields;
    }

}

class HomePage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }

}
```

Error:

```
[Notice] Array to string conversion
GET /<site_name>/dev/build

Line 396 in F:\Programs\XAMPP\htdocs\<site_Name>\sapphire\core\model\Database.php

Source

387                     $array_spec = $this->indexList[$table][$index_alt]['spec'];
388                 } else {
389                     $array_spec = $this->indexList[$table][$index_alt];
390                 }
391             }
392         }
393         
394         if($newTable || !isset($this->indexList[$table][$index_alt])) {
395             $this->transCreateIndex($table, $index, $spec);
396             $this->alterationMessage("Index $table.$index: created as $spec","created");
397         } else if($array_spec != DB::getConn()->convertIndexSpec($spec)) {
398             $this->transAlterIndex($table, $index, $spec);
399             $spec_msg=DB::getConn()->convertIndexSpec($spec);
400             $this->alterationMessage("Index $table.$index: changed to $spec_msg <i style=\"color: #AAA\">(from {$array_spec})</i>","changed");          
401         }
402     }
```

Comment: what's the error on dev/build?

Comment: @schellmax i've added it to the description :)

Comment: guess you're on php 5.4? you could try downgrading to php 5.3, upgrading silverstripe to 3.0, or disabling php warnings

Comment: @schellmax Is that really necessary? The Doco stuff seems to say >=5.2 for example here: http://www.versioneye.com/package/php--silverstripe--cms/version/2~4~9

Comment: version 2.4 doesn't seem to play well with 5.4, see e.g. http://www.silverstripe.org/installing-silverstripe/show/19456

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks very much. Not an easy one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was as Schellmax suggested, I've installed an earlier version of XAMPP with php 5.3 and it's working as it should now...